# Spidering server crashes website

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql

I have a server that is giving me MySQL server has gone away / connection timeout / connection refused errors when it is being crawled.  It also seems to slow down a lot at peak times when there are an number of users on the server.  I have a Magento Enterprise installation on this server. I am wondering could this be a problem with persistent connections or possibly something wrong with some of my settings in my.conf?

**Here is some information on my server:**

```
Processor #1
    Vendor
        GenuineIntel
    Name
        QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6)
    Speed
        2127.998 MHz
    Cache
        4096 KB

Processor #2
    Vendor
        GenuineIntel
    Name
        QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6)
    Speed
        2127.998 MHz
    Cache
        4096 KB

Processor #3
    Vendor
        GenuineIntel
    Name
        QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6)
    Speed
        2127.998 MHz
    Cache
        4096 KB

Processor #4
    Vendor
        GenuineIntel
    Name
        QEMU Virtual CPU version (cpu64-rhel6)
    Speed
        2127.998 MHz
    Cache
        4096 KB

RAM
    10GB

HDD
    200GB
```

**Here is my my.conf:**

```
[mysqld]
thread_concurrency=4
thread_cache_size=64
wait_timeout = 400
table_cache=2048
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=512M
query_cache_limit=512M
key_buffer_size=256M
max_allowed_packet=32M
max_connections=1000
tmp_table_size=1024M
max_heap_table_size=1024M
table_definition_cache=4000 
table_open_cache=4000
open_files_limit=65535
sort_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=1M
join_buffer_size=16M

innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=300
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=24M

tmpdir=/mysqltmp

log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

**At the time of these errors the server resources are as follows (from Munin):**

```
CPU = 395%
RAM (apps) = approx 6gb
I/O Stat (read/write) = approx -10k/10k
```

Comment: With the details you've given, it will be impossible for us to help you out. Please collect CPU, Memory, and Disk IO status during one of these episodes and post the results back here.

Comment: You need to define "Crashing" -- does the server go completely down (OS is dead, can't SSH in, can't log in on the console), or does the web server just stop responding? If the latter, is the webserver *crashed* (processes all dead), or simply *unresponsive* (overloaded and not accepting new requests)? Are there any messages in (any of) your log files that seem "interesting" around the times the server has "crashed"? etc. -- ***Please edit your question to include the necessary information and it may be reopened.***

Comment: Thanks @voretaq7 for your comments I have now updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like spiders are overloading you. Use [mysqltuner](https://raw.github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl) to check your mysql config.

Configure your database so it won't use more than 60% of system RAM.

Based on current information you have posted, decrease:

query_cache_size= (I'd start with 64M)

query_cache_limit= (I'd start with 1M)

wait_timeout = 400?! Equal this value to your apache timeout AND think about a user waiting 300 seconds for you to serve them response ;) (I'd start turning both mysql and apache down to 30 secs.)

**increase open_files_limit** if you have many tables (especially myisam) and don't forget 
your **system limits.conf**

If lowering buffers won't help, you can as well limit spiders with iptables :)